# Vim: How to write control characters in file

Tags: control-character

How do I write control characters in a file using Vim? For example, I want to write the backspace character, which is invoked using ^? (or the dedicated Backspace) key on the keyboard, to a file. But I can't seem to do that - everything I try just erases a character.

*The Unix Programming Environment* by Kernighan and Pike says (§2.1 *The basics of files*):

> It is important in each case to distinguish between how the character is
>   stored in a file and how it is interpreted in various situations. For example,
>   when you type a backspace on your keyboard (and assuming that your erase
>   character is backspace), the kernel interprets it to mean that you want to discard whatever character you typed previously. Both that character and the
>   backspace disappear, but the backspace is echoed to your terminal, where it
>   makes the cursor move one position backwards.
>
> If you type the sequence
>
> ```
> \←
> ```
>
> (i.e., `\` followed by a backspace), however, the kernel interprets that to mean that you want a literal backspace in your input, so the `\` is discarded and the byte `010` winds up in your file. When the backspace is echoed on your terminal, it moves the cursor to sit on top of the `\`.
>
> When you *print* a file that contains a backspace, the backspace is passed
>   uninterpreted to your terminal, which again will move the cursor one position
>   backwards. When you use `od` to display a file that contains a backspace, it
>   appears as a byte with value `010`, or, with the `-c` option, as `\b`.

Basically, it's saying that writing a backslash before backspace character should work (at least for ed). However I'm not able to write it using Vim. How can I write uncommon control characters into the file (such as backspace)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [CTRL-V](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-V) in Insert mode as a prefix to insert the next key as a literal expression.

So if you enter <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, you'll get a `^?` character inserted.

Another option, if you want to enter a character by its number, is to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> followed by a set of digits. (See [`:help i_CTRL-V_digit`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-V_digit).) A backspace character has code 127, so you can enter it with  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>, resulting on the same `^?` character.

(You can inspect the `^?` character with the [`ga`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#ga) command, which will show `<^?>  127,  Hex 7f,  Oct 177, Digr DT`, including the character code in decimal, hexadecimal and octal.)

In fact, one more way to enter this character is using Vim's [digraph](https://vimhelp.org/digraph.txt.html) support. In this case, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> followed by <kbd>D</kbd>, then <kbd>T</kbd>, both uppercase, to enter the same `^?` character. You can use the `:digraphs` command to get a table with all available digraphs.

Comment: Thank you excellent answer